# submit form on ENTER press int EXT js

Tags: javascript, extjs, submit

i am very new to EXT.js; i need to submit the form when ENTER is pressed below is my code but i dont know what to call in the listener of the password field here is my code: ie:what is the function to call in the listener

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();

    Ext.create("Ext.container.Viewport", {
        layout: "border",
        rtl: <spring:theme code='theme.rtl' text='false' />
    });


    Ext.create("Ext.window.Window", {
        title: "<spring:message code='title.login' text='Login' />",
        height: 310,
        width: 450,
        closable: false,
        layout: "border",
        items: [{
                xtype: "panel",
                border: false,
                bodyCls: "login-header",
                height: 160,
                region: "north"
            }, {
                id: "<%=loginFormId%>",
                url: "<spring:url value='/secure/auth'/>",
                xtype: "form",
                layout: "form",
                region: "center",
                bodyPadding: 10,
                border: false,
                buttons: [{
                        handler: function() {
                            var form = this.up("form").getForm();
                            if (form.isValid()) {
                                Ext.getCmp("<%=submitBtnId%>").disable();
                                form.standardSubmit = true;
                                form.method = "POST";
                                form.submit();

                            }
                        },
                        id: "<%=submitBtnId%>",
                        text: "<spring:message code='button.submit' text='Submit' />"
                    }, {
                        handler: function() {
                            var form = this.up("form").getForm();
                            form.reset();
                        },
                        id: "<%=clearBtnId%>",
                        text: "<spring:message code='button.clear' text='Clear' />"
                    }],

                defaultType: "textfield",
                defaults: {
                    msgTarget: "side",
                    labelWidth: 100
                },

                items: [{
                        fieldLabel: "<spring:message code='input.username' text='Username' />",
                        name: "selfcare_username"
                    }, {
                        fieldLabel: "<spring:message code='input.password' text='Password' />",
                        name: "selfcare_password",
                        enableKeyEvents:true,
                        inputType: "password",
                        listeners: {
                            scope: this,
                            specialkey: function(f, e) {
                                if (e.getKey() === e.ENTER) {

                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }]
            }]
    }).show();

<c:if test="${not empty param.error}">
    var errorMsg = "<c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />";
    if (errorMsg !== "") {
        Ext.MessageBox.show({
            title: "<spring:message code='title.error' text='Error' />",
            msg: errorMsg,
            closable: false,
            buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
        });
    }
</c:if>
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the listener to do:

```
listeners: {
                                keypress: function(textfield, e, options) {
                                    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                                        var form = this.up("form").getForm();
                                        if (form.isValid()) {
                                            Ext.getCmp("<%=submitBtnId%>").disable();
                                            form.standardSubmit = true;
                                            form.method = "POST";
                                            form.submit();

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```